# Unable to capture text from prompt by using UIAUTOMATER,Appium and python

Tags: android, python, appium

I am new to mobile automation.I am trying to automate login functionality for one android app.when ever i am clicking on login button without providing the username i am getting one prompt message like field cannot be empty. That alert box i am unable to capture through UIAUTOMATER.I want to get the string from prompt. Can somebody suggest how to proceed this .i am providing the image for getting clear idea.

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Q0XeTH2ihNs/VVMtk_BJvpI/AAAAAAAAAAk/YzIpNoPTwTM/w506-h281/uiautomater.JPG

Comment: Did you try it with Appium?

Comment: @Eugene yes i tried with appium.unable to capture the text.

Comment: Is this public app? Can I take it and play with it? Or may be you can provide the link to app with the similar behaviour?

Comment: Sorry @Eugene,i know this is really tough to help me without any code.But this is not the public app and i don't know any other app with the same behavior.

Comment: IF you have shield tablet or any shield devices,u can find shield hub application which has similar behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with `UIAutomatorviewer` simply not capturing toast messages. Now I solved it.

**OCR is the solution.**

I made already a full anser here: [Appium Toast Message](https://discuss.appium.io/t/verifying-toast/3676/21)

First install tesseract like this:

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract
```

Then you can use it as below in terminal:

```
tesseract example.jpg out
```

install pytesseract using pip:

```
pip install pytesseract
```

install pillow if not done yet:

```
pip install pillow
```

install tesseract-ocr:

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

Then use it in your python code like this:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

# path to your file
im = Image.open('test.png')
print pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
```

The steps are for Linux, but you get the idea.